# My bash script uses so much memory

Tags: linux, bash, memory-leaks

I was looking for which program is using my memory, where is leak?

And, I founded it, leak is at bash script.

But, how can it possible? Bash script will always alloc new space for each variable assignment?

My bash script is like the following, please let me know how can I correct this problem.

```
CONF="/conf/my.cfg"
HIGHRES="/data/high.dat"

getPeriod()
{
meas=`head -n 1 $CONF`
statperiod=`echo $meas`
}

(while true
do
        lastline=`tail -n 1 $HIGHRES |cut -d"," -f2`
        linenumber=`grep -n $lastline $HIGHRES | cut -f1 -d:`
        /bin/stat $linenumber
        getPeriod
        sleep $statperiod
done)
```

**EDIT #1:**
The last line of high.dat

```
2013-02-11,10:59:13,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12.340000,0.330000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24.730000,24.709990,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Where do you set $lastline?

Comment: Can you give an example of what's in `high.dat`?

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to verify a memory leak with a close approximation of that script, so maybe the leak isn't actually where you think it is. Consider updating your question with much more info, including a complete working example along with what you did to figure out that you had a memory leak.

That said, you have chosen quite an odd way to find out how many lines a file has. The most usual way would be to use the standard `wc` tool:

```
$ wc -l < test.txt
      19
$
```

Note: Use `< file` instead of passing the file name, since the latter will cause the file name to be written to stdout, and you'll then have to edit it away:

```
$ wc -l test.txt
      19 test.txt
$
```